# typescript + eslint + babel issue in expo project: lots of Parsing errors

Tags: typescript, expo, babeljs, eslint, eslintrc

eslint is giving me a really hard time

```
> Parsing error: The keyword 'const' is reserved. :eslint

> Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved. :eslint
```

> .eslintrc.js

```
const eslintConfig = require("@ourCompany/eslint-config");

module.export = {
  ...eslintConfig,
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
    jest: true,
    browser: true,
    commonjs: true,
  },
  parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
  parserOptions: {
    files: ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: "module",
    project: "./tsconfig.json",
  },
  plugins: [...eslintConfig.plugins, "@typescript-eslint"],
  extends: [
    ...eslintConfig.extends,
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
  ],
};
```

> tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~*": ["./*"]
    },
    "types": ["node", "jest"]
  }
}
```

> babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          alias: {
            ["~"]: "./",
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```